# Initializing and then returning a char array from a method

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a variable, *char x[]*, inside a method and then return it.

I'm getting: `address of stack memory associated with local variable 'x' returned`

This is because the memory allocated to x will be freed when the method finishes execution. To prevent this, I could declare the variable as static, *static char x[]* but then

I'm getting: `variable length array declaration cannot have 'static' storage duration`

Because I'm using another variable's length when declaring my *x* array.

I'm new to C, can someone tell me what is the best practice here? What should I do?

Comment: You should use [`malloc()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) instead of `new` to allocate in C.

Comment: @PaulR: This question is tagged C, but the first question you marked as a duplicate has two C++ answers first, neither of which will work in C, followed by two C answers that are inapplicable because they return pointers to static objects. The second question you marked as a duplicate is tagged C++ and not C. Further, it is a different question, and the answers there generally do not answer the question asked here.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: yes, I couldn't see a question that covered all the bases, and a lot of the duplicate linking seems to be between C and C++ questions - I think there's enough in the above linked dupes to answer the OP's question though ?

Comment: @PaulR: Where does any of the answers in the purported duplicates answer OP’s question about “What should I do?” by telling them to use `malloc`?

Comment: I expect this is a duplicate, but neither of those was, so I have reopened. The question can be reclosed as a duplicate when appropriate originals are found.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the length figured out, say in some variable named `length`, allocate memory for the data you are going to return:

```
char *Data = malloc(length * sizeof *Data);
if (!Data)
{
    fputs("Error, failed to allocate memory.\n", stderr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Then you can use `Data` as if it were an array of `char`. (`sizeof *Data` will be 1 in this case, but it is good practice to write memory allocations as `NumberOfItems * sizeof *Pointer` as this automatically matches the size request to the size of the objects being allocated, in case the types change in future program revisions.)

When you return memory in this way, the caller is responsible for releasing it, and this should be stated in documentation for the function that allocates memory.  (Often, when a function allocates memory, a paired function is provided that deallocates the memory. This is trivial and may be omitted when only a simple `free(pointer)` is required. It is more apropos when complicated data structures are allocated in multiple parts, and the routine to free them has more work to do.)

Answer (score 0):

One way it to use `malloc`:

```
char* get_str(void) {
    char* str = malloc(12 + 1); // +1 for the '\0' terminator
    strcpy(str, "Hello world!");
    return str;
}
void func(void) {
    char* str = get_str();
    // Be sure to free it when you're done:
    free(str);
}
```

Or you could create the array beforehand and pass it to the function:

```
void initalize_str(size_t len, char* str) {
    strncpy(str, "Hello world!", len);
}

void func(void) {
    char s[128];
    initalize_str(128, s);
}
```